# OpenCV: how to get GMM parameters?

Tags: c++, opencv, background, gaussian, mixture-model

I am using `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2` to do background subtraction, and I've manually set the number of mixture model to be used as follows:

```
cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 myModel;
myModel.set("nmixtures",5);
```

Now I want to display the actual mixture number on the screen to check whether it is working correctly or not. For this, I've tried `'myModel.getParams("nmixtures")'` and `'myModel.bgmodelUsedModes'`, etc. but all failed. I am using OpenCV2.4.5 version. How can I get the actual parameters that GMM is using? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it by myself. It should be '`myModel.getInt("nmixtures")`'.